# AvalonEdit: Highlight the text in between Beginning and End elements

Tags: .net, wpf, syntax-highlighting, avalonedit

I'm using AvalonEdit and have a custom highlight rules file, I've got this this rule...

```
<Span ruleSet="ASP" multiline="true">
    <Begin color="ASPSectionStartEndTags">&lt;script</Begin>
    <End color="ASPSectionStartEndTags">script&gt;</End>
</Span>
```

...which is highlighting the `<script` and `script>` elements in my editor but I'd like to highlight the whole script block.

What do I need to add?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `color` attribute on the `<Span>`, not just on the begin/end rules.